# How to pass argument to Mongo Script

Tags: javascript, mongodb, scripting

I've been using mongo and script files like this:

```
$ mongo getSimilar.js
```

I would like to pass an argument to the file:

```
$ mongo getSimilar.js apples
```

And then in the script file pick up the argument passed in.

```
var arg  = $1;
print(arg);
```

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Use `--eval` and use shell scripting to modify the command passed in.

`mongo --eval "print('apples');"`

Or make global variables (credit to Tad Marshall):

```
$ cat addthem.js
printjson( param1 + param2 );
$ ./mongo --nodb --quiet --eval "var param1=7, param2=8" addthem.js
15
```

Comment: This doesn't work with mapreduce, the reduce() function doesn't have access to the params (ReferenceError: ... is not defined near ...)

Comment: --eval is very useful. say we want to quickly change secondary to become primary in a replication set. Use a script `conf = rs.conf()
conf.members.forEach(
    function (member) { 
     member.priority = 0.5
    }
)

conf.members[memberId].priority = 1 // 
rs.reconfig(conf)` save this script in chooseprimary.js and run with `mongo --eval "var memberId=3" chooseprimary.js` . memberId should be the id of the secondary you wish to become primary. Just make sure to execute mongo --eval on the Primary server. :)

Answer (score 29):

You can't do that, but you could put them in another script and load that first:

```
// vars.js
msg = "apples";
```

and getSimilar.js was:

```
print(msg);
```

Then:

```
$ mongo vars.js getSimilar.js
MongoDB shell version: blah
connecting to: test
loading file: vars.js
loading file: getSimilar.js
apples
```

Not quite as convenient, though.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the info!  I've got a few scripts that would be a little tough to `--eval`.

Answer (score 3):

Set a shell var:

```
password='bladiebla'
```

Create js script:

```
cat <<EOT > mongo-create-user.js
print('drop user admin');
db.dropUser('admin');
db.createUser({
user: 'admin',
pwd: '${password}',
roles: [ 'readWrite']
});
EOT
```

Pass script to mongo:

```
mongo mongo-create-user.js
```

Comment: this does not work with 2.4.  Can you point to documentation or expand on this?

Answer (score 3):

2022 update:

when using `mongosh` you can read the execution arguments from `process.argv`

```
mongosh script.js param1 param2 
// process.argv will be [.... , 'param1', param2']
```

the tricky bit is that `mongosh` will try to execute the parameters (e.g. `param1` and `param2`) as additional scripts, but this can be prevented by ending the script using `quit()`. (TBH, I'm not sure it's by design / intended / documented)

Comment: How about:   
`param1=yourParamValue mongosh $mongoUrl script.js --quiet`  
and access the param in javascript with `process.env.param1`.  
That works perfectly in Mac and unix. On Windows it's slightly [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69857831/how-can-i-pass-environment-params-inline-on-windows-cmd).

Answer (score 1):

I used a shell script to pipe a mongo command to mongo. In the mongo command I used an arg I passed to the shell script (i.e. i used `$1`):

```
#!/bin/sh

objId=$1
EVAL="db.account.find({\"_id\" : \"$objId\"})"
echo $EVAL | mongo localhost:27718/balance_mgmt --quiet
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `find({\"_id\" : ObjectId(\"$objId\")})`?  Or is there a way to set mongo so that you don't have to use the `ObjectId()` guy?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small utility to solve the problem for myself. With the `mongoexec` utility, you would be able to run the command `./getSimilar.js apples` by adding the following to the beginning of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/mongoexec --quiet
```

Within the script, you can then access the arguments as `args[0]`.

https://github.com/pveierland/mongoexec

Comment: Doesn't work; I'm getting access denied.  `sudo` doesn't do the trick.  Changing the shebang to point to the executable located in user directory (rather than /usr/bin) doesn't work.  Was all excited to use it.  Wish I could get it to work.

Comment: @Bear The instructions fail to mention that the script must be executable. If you run "sudo chmod +rx /usr/bin/mongoexec" it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem, by using the javascript bundler parcel: https://parceljs.org/

With this, one can use node environment variables in a script like:

```
var collection = process.env.COLLECTION;
```

when building with parcel, the env var gets inlined:

```
parcel build ./src/index.js --no-source-maps
```

The only downside is, that you have to rebuild the script every time you want to change the env vars. But since parcel is really fast, this is not really a problem imho.