# How do I handle command-line arguments in a mongo script?

Tags: javascript, bash, mongodb

I've been working on some simple scripts to run on mongo from the bash command-line. Originally, I ran them as follows:

```
$ mongo dbname script.js
```

but I recently came across mikemaccana's answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/23909051/2846766, indicating the use of mongo as an interpreter so I can just execute script.js (or any name I choose, with or without the .js) from the command line.

```
$ script.js
```

I think it's brilliant and clean, but now I'd like to pass in a database name as a command line argument.

```
$ script.js dbname
```

Here I use the bash-style "$1" to demonstrate what I'm doing in script.js.

```
#!/usr/bin/env mongo
var db = new Mongo().getDB($1);
// Do other things with db, once I resolve the name from the command line.
```

This results in a "ReferenceError: $1 is not defined ...", which is not surprising. But how would I reference command line arguments? Is this going to be a mongo convention? a javascript convention? Is it possible? It would make my command-line experience with mongo much better aesthetically.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no way to do this using the mongo shell...

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/-pO7Cec6Sjc

... try using a bash script (or other scripting language you are comfortable with) if you want to get a similar command line experience.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate of [How to pass argument to Mongo Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114355/how-to-pass-argument-to-mongo-script)
In a nutshell, this is not possible but several workarounds are given in the answers (not repeated here).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass args to your script through

`mongo --eval 'var databasePassword="password"' script.js`

and you can access databasePassword value inside `script.js`

`db.auth({ user: 'testUser, pwd: databasePassword });`