# getting problem with condition in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, conditional-statements

See my condition does work fine for my history's first collection but for second it does not work either If I replace my specified id with `5e4a8d2d3952132a08ae5724` that exists in my second object of history's collection return me all data which is not correct because it's date is greater then main collection's date so it should return me nothing please suggest how to fix it.

```
db.main.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "history",
      localField: "history_id",
      foreignField: "history_id",
      as: "History"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$History"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "5e4a8d2d3952132a08ae5764",
              "$History.user_id"
            ]
          },
          then: {
            $and: [
              {
                $gt: [
                  "$date",
                  "$History.date"
                ]
              },
              {
                $eq: [
                  "5e4a8d2d3952132a08ae5764",
                  "$History.user_id"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          else: {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

when I put two object into history collection it does not work either [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mf4C8ccNcSc)

Here is working playground with single history object https://mongoplayground.net/p/hrNofrq1c3S

Comment: Waiting for some magical response

Comment: I think you want to filter the documents?

Comment: that's true but confusing how to do it

Comment: Could you post your expected output and on what conditions you want to filter the documents??

Comment: My question is simple filter out records from main collection which has lesser date than history's collection based on specified user_id here is configuration https://mongoplayground.net/p/hrNofrq1c3S

Comment: This link is not working, it's showing 'no document found, when I am running the query.

Comment: Yes that's correct because history date 1587650683440 is bigger then main collection date. Also keep in mind if specified data does not match should return all data from main collection, I am stucking when history's collection has more than one object.

Comment: add the expected output and what you have so far.

Comment: Main collection data base on filter or fulfil condition like this https://mongoplayground.net/p/u3UVrAMarYr

Comment: Check this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/pR4EurjOISe

Comment: can't we do compare with specified id let's say I will pass specified id and then compare.. ?

Comment: Why I am saying because I want to pass user_id that will check in history's collection if possible @ngShravil.py it will say like cond: {
            $lt: [
              "$$his.date",
              "$date"
            ]
          } and specified $eq: [
              "5e4a8d2d3952132a08ae5764",
              "$History.user_id"
            ] ?

Comment: This will help you with passing the arguments to MongoDB query: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10114802/6635464

Comment: where and how to pass this could you please make a demo inside playground ?

Comment: I think it's not possible in MongoPlayGround.

Comment: One case is failing here it should return all data if history collection is null and specified id does not match it should return all data see https://mongoplayground.net/p/X2B58D_SuLl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason, why your query (which is posted in the OP) is not working because, you have not specified anything in `else` part. So, the better approach will be with '$filter' operator.

You can try the below:

```js
db.main.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "history",
      localField: "history_id",
      foreignField: "history_id",
      as: "History"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "History": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$History",
          as: "his",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              {
                $lt: [
                  "$$his.date",
                  "$date"
                ]
              },
              {
                $eq: [
                  "5e4a8d2d3952132a08ae5764",
                  "$$his.user_id"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      data: 1,
      history_id: 1,
      sender_id: 1,
      text: 1,
      date: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$History"
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayGroundLink](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5LGWOQtfH_M)

Comment: Thank you buddy that really help me

Comment: One case is failing here it should return all data if history collection is null and specified id does not match it should return all data see https://mongoplayground.net/p/X2B58D_SuLl

Comment: Can yo please look into this I tried doesn't work for me

Comment: I am waiting for your response even created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61514726/mongodb-if-then-condition-under-filter-how-to-make