# Mongodb if then condition under filter how to make

Tags: mongodb, filter, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, conditional-statements

```
db.main.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "history",
      localField: "history_id",
      foreignField: "history_id",
      as: "History"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "History": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$History",
          as: "his",
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "5e4a8d2d3952132a08ae5764",
              "$$his.user_id"
            ]
          },
          then: {
            cond: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $lt: [
                    "$$his.date",
                    "$date"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "5e4a8d2d3952132a08ae5764",
                    "$$his.user_id"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          else: {}
        }
      },
      data: 1,
      history_id: 1,
      sender_id: 1,
      text: 1,
      date: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$History"
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QSuIKRec8KJ)

Play with if condition under filter getting error. My purpose is specified user_id match with history's user_id then condition work other wise not.

How to fix it please guide or alternative approaches are welcome.

Comment: @whoami only need to set this condition if {
                  $eq: [
                    "5e4a8d2d3952132a08ae5764",
                    "$$his.user_id"
                  ]
                }

then filter work otherwise no else :{} Is there any chance any one please ?

Comment: I think I've seen this queystion asked 3 or 4 different times, and I'm still not sure what you are trying to accomplish.  if you could explain, step by step, what you want to compare, and how that relates to which documents you want matched, we could help you with this query.

Comment: Any chat room we can talk for better explanation ?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212837/mongodb-if-then-condition-under-filter-how-to-make

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion in chat, it seems the overall problem was how to select documents from the main collection based on 2 criteria of the related history documents:

```
db.main.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
      from: "history",
      localField: "history_id",
      foreignField: "history_id",
      as: "History"
  }},
  {$match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          false,
          {$reduce: {
              input: "$History",
              initialValue: false,
              in: {
                $or: [
                  "$$value",
                  {$and: [
                      {$eq: [
                          "$$this.user_id",
                          ObjectId("5e4a8d2d3952132a08ae5764")
                      ]},
                      {$gte: [
                          "$$this.date",
                          "$date"
                      ]}
                  ]}
                ]
              }
          }}
        ]
      }
  }}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/84cdcBdkJWW)

Comment: @Joe The user changes OP several times, so you will never find the correct result.