# How can i pass environment params inline on windows cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, environment-variables

i need to run a script with node on windows like:

```
HOST=www.host.com node index.js
```

but this showme a error like
`"HOST" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo`*

---

*English Translation: `"HOST" is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to run both the `set` command to set your `Host` environment variable in the same line that you run your script with `node`. Running two commands one after an other is possible in the command line with the `&` and `&&` operators.

From [ss64](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

> ```
> commandA &  commandB      Run commandA and then run commandB
> commandA && commandB      Run commandA, if it succeeds then run commandB
> ```

Here, since you likely don't want to continue to executing your node script if you are unable to set the environment variable, you would likely want to opt for the `&&` operator for this use case.

---

#### Final Code:

```
set "HOST=www.host.com" && node index.js
```

---

#### Note:

`SET` in this context will never return an error. As such, both `&` and `&&` are functionally identical for this use case.